# jqgrid: how to create the add dialog each time it is opened

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-select2

I have a jqgrid plugin whose add dialog contains the select2 plugin. I have spent a lot of time trying to clear select2 data when dialog is opened but apparently it is not possible, so I think that if dalog is recreated each time it is opened, I could solve the problem. So the question is how to recreate the add dialog every time it is opened.

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the editFormOptions.recreatForm : true ;

recreateForm    When set to true the form is recreated every time the dialog is activeted with the new options from colModel (if they are changed).